# CodeIgniter not accessing vars inside if... else statements correctly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am getting errors saying $id1 and $id2 are undefined. Am I not accessing them right? If not how do I access them correctly?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM churchMembers");
$row = $query->row();
    if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {
      if ($postingUserId == $row->cMuserId) { // check to see what church the posting user is a member of
        $id1 = $row->cMchurchId; // if posting user is a member of a church set it to var id1
      } 
      if ($userid == $row->cMuserId) { // check to see what church myuserid is a member of
        $id2 = $row->cMchurchId; // if myuserid is a member of a church set it to var2
      } 
      if ($id1 == $id2) { // if posting user and myuserid are a member of the same church process the following
        echo json_encode(array('loggedIn' => true, 'isMembershipSame' => true));
      } 
      elseif ($id1 != $id2) { // if posting user and myuserid are not a member of the same user process the following
        echo json_encode(array('loggedIn' => true, 'isMembershipSame' => false));
      }
    }
```

Comment: We don't see the context here. Where is `$row` defined?

Comment: I reformatted your linebreaks to make the logic easier to understand (for us and for you)

Comment: Thanks and I edited it to show where $row is coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define either `$id1` or `$id2` unless their corresponding `if` conditions are met, so if either of the preceding conditions is false and doesn't run, neither variable exists when you attempt to compare them in `if ($id1 == $id2)`.

You should initialize them to empty strings before entering your if chain.  Then when you compare them, also verify that they are non-empty:

```
// ADDENDUM after comments:
// If you put this into a loop to fetch rows,
// the following must be INSIDE the loop to reinitialize
// the two vars on each iteration.

// Initialize them as empty strings
$id1 = "";
$id2 = "";

// If you are in a loop, you should check num_rows() once outside the loop, rather than inside
if ($query->num_rows() != 0) {
  if ($postingUserId == $row->cMuserId) {
    $id1 = $row->cMchurchId;
  } 
  if ($userid == $row->cMuserId) {
    $id2 = $row->cMchurchId;
  } 
  // Test if they are non-empty (conditions matched above) and equal:
  if (!empty($id1) && !empty($id2) && $id1 == $id2) {
    echo json_encode(array('loggedIn' => true, 'isMembershipSame' => true));
  } 
  // No need for else if here, just a plain else clause
  else {
    echo json_encode(array('loggedIn' => true, 'isMembershipSame' => false));
  }
}
```

Comment: When I click the Network tab in Chrome Developer Toolbox, it sends the request but nothing no json is returned. I'm guessing $id1 and $id2 are truly empty

Comment: Yep, I added random data to the empty $id1 and $id2 vars and the json_encode is outputting data in the network tab. so something is going wrong. i need to be pulling the data from: `$id1 = $row->cMchurchId;` and `$id2 = $row->cMchurchId;` and not `$id1 = "";` and `$id2 = "";`

Comment: `var_dump($row);` to verify what's in there.

Comment: So I added a foreach loop because it was only returning one row. but now isMembershipSame is returning false on all of the returned rows when it should be returning true on at least one. this is a problem that I don't have a clue as to what is causing it.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby Since you put it into a loop, you must reinitialize `$id1, $id2` to empty strings at the start of every loop iteration, right inside the top of the `foreach`.